# How to fix "Invalid or unexpected token", caused by inline break?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with my string replace function, because the data out of my database has a break and messes with my jQuery syntax, but I don't know how to fix it properly.

I know the problem, but I can't solve it. I did put everything in the same string using '' or "" but didn't work.

```
$('#clipboard_textarea').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace('$text_boxtype', '<?php echo $text_boxtype; ?>'));
});
```

I expect the output:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="col-md-12 feature_box"><h3 class="box_headline"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Artikelbeschreibung <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3><p>Artikelbeschreibung</p></div></div>
```

The problem is, that the output is corrupted by the data of $text_boxtype. Which ends up changing the code to:

```
$('#clipboard_textarea').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text.replace('$text_boxtype', '<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="col-md-12 feature_box"><h3 class="box_headline"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Artikelbeschreibung <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></h3><p>Artikelbeschreibung</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div></div>'));
```

Comment: Quick fix: use template literals: ```text.replace('$text_boxtype', `<?php echo $text_boxtype; ?>`)```, but this will not work in IE. Better fix: remove the line breaks in your PHP

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan even better fix, avoid generating JS from PHP and instead just have the JS code separate from PHP. Share the *data* between them.

Comment: Very true. That should be *Best fix* :)

Comment: What is the value of $text_boxtype? Where are your extra <p> tags coming from?

Comment: @dpDesignz The value of $text_boxtype varies. It comes from a previous form that allows the user to input a description-text with standart tags like <strong> etc. The current output is the "expected" output mentioned before.

Comment: So you're trying to get what they've entered in and put it in a new textbox or just output it to the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the newlines in your text with what looks to JS like an escaped newline:

```
<?php echo str_replace("\n", "\\\n", $text_boxtype); ?>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4HgjN)